# Improving Spark performance: is it enough to use a cluster?

Tags: performance, apache-spark, cluster-computing, apache-spark-mllib, recommendation-engine

I have developed a simple Spark application that analyzes a dataset. The data analyzed comes from a CSV of 2 million records and 25 attributes. The analysis relates to simple transformations/actions of RDDs and I also used the MLlib library algorithms.
Being my first experience I've taken many pieces of code from documentation or examples present online. However, for a complete execution of a simple algorithm ALS of User Recommendation, for example, it takes several minutes.
I use the application on a laptop (i7 2GHz, 12GB RAM).
I would like to know if I only need to use this application in a cluster of computers to increase performance (in terms of speed) and if so, it is normal that running a Recommendation Engine Model in local takes so long time.
If yes, with a good cluster of computer can I get results in real time?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My gut says you will not save much time, as there is overhead associated with both Spark itself and the cluster. You honestly might save time not using Spark at all, assuming you are not planning on working with a larger data set.

Comment: Can you show your code? When you execute your code, do you see log with lots of Shuffle ?

Comment: @hoyland I chose Spark just because it is considered the fastest framework for doing this kind of analysis ("up to 100 times faster than Hadoop MapReduce") so it sounds odd that with such a "small" dataset takes so long.

Comment: @mprabhat I only see a lot of stages: I also get 300 stages to do some Map operation on RDDs and then apply a complete Recommendation Engine (User and Product Recommendations)